# Problems sculpting texture onto cylinders

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

I'm using alphas to sculpt fur onto a 3d model I'm making. When I sculpt onto the arms, specifically the sides  of  the arms, the texture comes out really jagged and messed up and I'm not sure how to fix it. The best I can do right now is smooth it out, but then it stops looking like fur so I want to try avoiding that if possible.

Not messed  up

[image: Not messed up texture]

Messed up

[image: Messed up texture]

Any tips on how  to fix this is appreciated.

[image]
Blend exchange

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I currently can't tell why but when you turn off `Front Faces Only` under `Tool` -> `Advanced` -> `Front Faces Only` it works fine.
[image]

Additionally when working with a multires modifier I recommend to have a base mesh consisting only of homogenous (equal sized) quads. Since your mesh is triangularized, you can easily get an "only quads" mesh but switching to edit mode and executing the operator `Tris to Quads`. Aftwards, by selecting a quad and pressing `SHIFT + G` (`Select Similar`) ->`Polygon Sides` and inverting the selection (`CMD + I`) you can check if any non-quads remained on the mesh and fix it manually. For checking how many (non-quad) faces are selected you can turn on `Statistics`:

[image]

Before working in sculpt mode I recommend to put some loop cuts across the mesh to get quads of equals sizes. I hope that helps.